# accessing the values from a belongs_to table

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to get the values from a belongs_to table in my controller (so i can use these values to insert into another model.

```
class AccesspointsController < ApplicationController

  def create

   @accesspoint = Accesspoint.new(params[:accesspoint])
   @accesspoint.build_radgroupcheck(:value => params[:accesspoint][:shortname], :groupname => params[:user][:email])

  end 

end
```

the other model is radgroupcheck while i am trying to get the email data from the user table. and copy insert it over to radgroupcheck. the other params are ok (accesspoint and shortname to the same radgroupcheck table)

while doing :groupname => params[:user][:email] - i get a nil (because the params are not from the controller i am using though i am using this controller to add everything)

How do i go about getting the params from another model (with the user already registered with the email) -  the accesspoint model belongs_to the user model.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: sorry about that.. added the question.

Comment: Since user is already registered, you will have to fetch the user from database and then associate it with @accesspoint.

Comment: How do i do that? I have tried :groupname => [:user.current_id.email]

Comment: I had tried :groupname => accesspoint.user.email but the error i got is undefined local variable or method `accesspoint' for #<AccesspointsController:0x00000004d38750>. doing this in views is fine, no problem.

Comment: If you are using Devise you can do :groupname => current_user.email

Comment: Yes. i am using Devise. It is what i was looking for. Thank you. :)